# Как происходит конкатенация констант в java?

Tags: java

Как происходит конкатенация констант в java? Тоже через  StringBuilder, как обыкновенные строки? Оптимизируются ли они на этапе компиляции, если конкатенируются только константы (допустим, в одну большую константу)?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Оптимизируются. В итоге будет одна константа. Откомпилируйте и посмотрите на байт-код.